# Security running a private live WAMP server including SVN

Tags: security, svn, wamp

I have installed the latest WAMP server from http://www.wampserver.com/ on a VPS Windows 2003 machine for development purposes between a team of programmers that are geographically distributed around the world.  We have also installed the CollabNet SVN server that is working over HTTP.

I am concerned about security - even though this *is not* supposed to be a SVN repository or web site accessible to the general public but my distributed team needs to access the web server remotely via their web browsers.

Since installing WAMP I put a password on the MYSQL database that I believe shouldn't be accessible if I switch the WAMP to online mode.  But I am worried I need to do more to secure the system.  Obviously I need to password protect the main root of the web server, and my team will switch it offline when not in use but when it is in use what else should I do to protect it?

Due to the nature of the application we are writing we must run on Windows so no answers involving Linux please :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say your concerned about security,  yet you use Windows.  That blows my mind.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing sometimes you just have too.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there should be only a few ports open to the general public: `80` for whatever you do on Apache, <strike>and the SVN port(s) (can't remember what those were).</strike> And, obviously, the RDP port if you administer the machine through it.

Check out [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/129404/win-2003-sbs-secure-enough-by-default) on general Windows 2003 SBS security I asked on Serverfault a few months ago, there are some brilliant answers on what to take care of.